# geotiffread function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gis

I have a "Tiff" file which is taken by landsat 7, band 3. I want to reach its geo tiff info. However when I try to perform "geotiffread" function on that image it says:

```
     ?? Error using ==> geotiffinfo>readinfo
     Multiple images exist in the file and the HEIGHT or WIDTH values are not equal.

     Error in ==> geotiffinfo at 215
     info  = readinfo(filename);

     Error in ==> geotiffread at 82
     info  = geotiffinfo(filename);
```

From the error message I understand that I need to split the tiff file and take the same height and width portion of the image. In other to solve this issue I perform the following operation:

```
     >> h = imread(data,1);
     >> z = h(1:7000, 1:7000);
     >> imwrite(z, 'deneme.tif');
     >> geotiffread('deneme.tif');
```

it gives the following error:

```
     ??? Error using ==> geotiffinfo>readinfo
     The file 'C:\......\deneme.tif' does not contain GeoTIFF Tags.

     Error in ==> geotiffinfo at 215
     info  = readinfo(filename);

     Error in ==> geotiffread at 82
     info  = geotiffinfo(filename);
```

How can I solve this problem? How can I read the geotiff info from tiff images? Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imwrite function only writes image data. If you have the georeferencing information available you can try using the geotiffwrite function instead:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27959

If you are just interested in the geotiff info, then you can use the geotiffinfo function on your original image.